# MinGW unexpected "A" character at the end of function declaration

Tags: c++, mingw

I'm using MinGW to compile my `.cpp` and I keep having this error:

```
In file included from c:\mingw\include\_mingw.h:73:0,
             from c:\mingw\include\wchar.h:53,
             from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:44,
             from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\postypes.h:40,
             from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\iosfwd:40,
             from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\ios:38,
             from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
             from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
             from file.hpp:6,
             from file.cpp:1:
file.cpp: In constructor 'File::File(bool, std::__cxx11::string)':
file.cpp:19:37: error: 'class X' has no member named 'LoadImageA'; did you mean 'LoadImage'?
Image image= m_X.LoadImage("image.png");
```

It just make no sense, because you can obviously see that there is no `A` in `LoadImage`.

When I put the `A`, the code compile, but I don't want to put a random letter at the end of my function name.

It look like an encoding problem, but I'm very not sure.

Why MinGW can't compile this code which contain obviously no error?

Comment: Welcome to macro substitution. Microsoft has a ton of macros that, 20 years ago, made it easy to switch code between good ol' ANSI (suffixed with A) and unicode (suffixed with W) by calling a function with no suffix at all.  Looks like you've tripped over one.

Comment: But it is very strange, because I used this function before in other files, and I had no problem; It is only when I use it in this file that it cause me this problem...

Comment: Likely a file you included in this file defines (or includes a field that defines) the  `#define LoadImage LoadImageA` macro.

Comment: Ok, I found it. It is because of `pthread.h`. Thank you.

Comment: @Trytio -- the actual culprit is `"windows.h"`. It's possible that `pthread.h` pulls that header in, but it seems unlikely.

Comment: No, I checked all the `include`: `pthread.h -> _ptw32.h -> ptw32_errno.h -> winsock.h -> windows.h`.